# What is another word for share in the context of a blog?

Tags: synonyms

What is another word for **share** in the context of sharing a blog article on twitter, facebook, etc..?

Comment: Are you trying to come up with some kind of prompt or text for a button on a website?

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald Yep, instead of saying _Share this:_ and showing a bunch of share buttons, I'd like it to be something not so widely used.

Answer (score 0):

**Show**
Might be most appropriate for videos or images rather than text. We watch and look at those whereas we read text.

**Give**
If it's something the recipient will have afterwards, it could be a gift you shared with them. But it implies a transfer of ownership.

**Post**, **Publish**, or **Announce**
To make something public. Shouting it to the world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want edgy I like **fire**.  Fire it off.

Something more laid back is **distribute**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

*Spread* this (connects with the idea of something going viral)

also
*Circulate* this
*Promote* this

Answer (score -1):

**Inform** if your blog is heady or hoity-toity.

**Infect** if your blog is just that hip, or medical-related.

**Gossip** if your blog is anything like TMZ.